# Relation between two sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $B$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of an interval, say, $I=[a,b]$. Set $P=\{b\cup m:b\in B, m \text{ is a meager subset of } I \text{ having Lebesgue measure zero} \}$, and $Q=\{b\cup m:b\in B, m \text{ is a subset of } I \text{ having Lebesgue measure zero} \}$. Here are my questions:

1) Is it true that $P\subset Q$? Taking any $p\in P$, $p=b\cup m$ for some Borel set $b$ and meager set $m$ of measure zero. This implies that $p\in Q$ as $m$ is of measure zero.

2) I don not have any idea about the other direction.

3) As I understand, the set $Q$ is exactly the set of all Lebesgue measurable sets, i.e. the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets.

Comment: $P$ is the set of all doodads that are also blumpinks. $Q$ is the set of all blumpinks. Is $P$ a subset of $Q$?

Comment: hmmm, thanks for your comment. Okay, now, $Q\subset P$. Could you point to my mistake in proving 1).

Comment: @BadrAlharbi - Look again at Asaf's comment. Your conclusion is backwards. $P \subset Q$, not $Q \subset P$. This is essentially your proof (1). Asaf is just pointing out to you that you were making some big thing of it when in fact it is obvious. For (2), you will need to prove that the intersection of a Borel set and a set of measure $0$ is also meager. For (3), $Q$ defined as being only *measur*e $0$ sets! So obviously it is not all measurable sets.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks your comment. Regarding (1), I am getting confused whether $P\subset Q$ or vice versa. "Your conclusion is backwards. $P\subset Q$, not $Q\subset P$". Did you mean that (1) $P\subset Q$ is correct?

Comment: Yes. The requirements to belong to $Q$ are also all requirements to belong to $P$. $P$ just adds an additional requirement. For this, It doesn't even matter what the additional requirement is. If $s \in P$, then $s$ also satisfies the requirements to belong to $Q$, so $s \in Q$. That implication: $\forall s, s \in P \implies s \in Q$ is the definition of $P \subset Q$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks a lot.